# How to use Wayland for the gdm login screen?

Tags: 20.04, gdm, wayland

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and would like to use Wayland as the GDM login screen, to avoid the gnome-shell owned by gdm consuming my RAM.

`WaylandEnable=false` is disabled in my /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

Comment: You can select Wayland at the login screen. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @ChaganAuto, no I cannot, my gdm is using X11, theres no cog or anything

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change your login screen to use Wayland, edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

**Uncomment**, and change **#WaylandEnable=false** to **WaylandEnable=true**.

Save the file and reboot.

**Note**: If you wish to use Wayland as your DE, at the login screen, select your username, then click on the icon in the lower-right of your screen, and select Wayland. You may not be able see this icon if you're using Nvidia. Some mods required for Nvidia 470. Nvidia 510 might work better. Although this link is not from the Nvidia web site, it'll give you some idea... https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2021/debian-ubuntu-linux-mint-nvidia-guide/4/

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: @Deltab Exactly what are you looking at that makes you think that it's not working? Show me `grep -i wayland /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.

Comment: @heynnema The OP is either severely mistaken, not actually using Ubuntu but some weird unofficial (like in one of their first questions here and it went by unnoticed) or just trolling.

Comment: @ChanganAuto i'm not a troll, just look at my profile page

Comment: @heynnema I still have a gnome-shell instance owned by user gdm after login. AFAIK this issue is not supposed to happen with Wayland.

Comment: @Deltab I did :) That's exactly where I found your other questions and at least one of them off-topic. Are you really using Ubuntu?

Comment: yes, ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @Deltab You didn't show me the output of the grep command that I asked for two days ago. On the login screen, select your username, then click on the icon in the lower-right of your screen, and select Wayland there.

Comment: the cog is not showing up :( 
the output is ```WaylandEnable=true```

Comment: @Deltab Do you have an Nvidia card? If so, what version driver?

Comment: yes, 470.103.01, so I should be able to get Wayland working

Comment: @Deltab With 470 you have to make some mods to your system for it to kinda work. 510 might be a better choice, if it supports your card. Go to the nvidia web site to get that info. My answer did enable Wayland for the login screen.

Comment: @Deltab Although not from the Nvidia forums or support site, see https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2021/debian-ubuntu-linux-mint-nvidia-guide/4/

Comment: @heynnema it worked!!, ty so much, not having to deal with a process stealing 1.9 GB of my RAM is great